# Store AM/PM from time input in local storage JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm creating a website that users need to put there check in time in time input and store it to local storage. I can only store the time but not the AM/PM. Why I can't store AM/PM on local storage from my time input?
[image]

```
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="txtcheckintime" name="checkintime" required="">

<script>
      function passvalues(){
        var checkintime=document.getElementById("txtcheckintime").value;
        localStorage.setItem("checkintime", checkintime);
        
  return true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What actually ends up getting stored for times 12:00 PM and beyond?  I suspect the value will be stored in 24-hour time ..... or, at least, when JavaScript gets the value from the controls, it's probably the 24-hour equivalent.  Have you done and alert() on the "checkintime" variable to see what it is actually holding (after it's retrieve the element's value)?  I believe that different browsers (and perhaps users' regional settings) will affect how the "time" input actually displays within the page ... but the underlying value should be valid

Comment: I just did a quick test myself - with 6:37 AM, "checkintime" value is "06:37".  With 6:37 PM, "checkintime" value is "18:37".  That's a test using Chrome.  Not sure if other browsers may have a different result

Comment: OT - It's a good practice to use 24-hour format to store time `H:i:s` (`13:00:00`). And `Y-m-d H:i:s` (`2021-04-26 14:23:00`) if dates are involved.

Answer (score 0):

local storage can store only string. how about using `toString()` and `parse()`?

Answer (score 0):

HTML input (type="time") control underlying value is in 24-hour format.  Different browsers will render the "time" control in different ways, but if user selects, for example, 6:37 AM, the value retrieved from the control should be "06:37".  Conversely, if user selects 6:37 PM, then the value retrieved from the control should be "18:37".

Answer (score 0):

The value of `<input type="time">` is a string in 24 hour format: `HH:MM` Range of `HH` is `00 - 23` and `MM` is `00 - 59`. Convert that string into the 12 hour format then add it to `localStorage`.

The following Snippet consists of a form of two inputs, a function to convert 24 hour to 12 hour format, and a function that tests the form values. The `localStorage` does not work on this site due to security concerns so it's commented out. Follow the directions commented in `testForm(tiime)` to convert it into using `localStorage` when testing in an environment other than SO or similar sites.

Details are commented in example below.

```js
const form = document.forms[0];
form.onchange = testForm;

function testForm(event) {
  const field = event.target;
  const ID = field.id;
  const val = field.value;
  console.log('Original Value ' + val);
  const finalTime = convertTime(val);

  /* 1. Remove `//` from the next 3 lines to use localStorage */
  // localStorage.setItem(ID, finalTime);
  // const result = localStorage.getItem(ID);
  // console.log(ID + ' ' + result);

  /* 2. Add `//` to the next 2 lines to use localStorage */
  const result = ID + ' ' + finalTime;
  console.log(result);
}

// Pass the 24 hour formatted time string (`00-23`:`00-59`)
function convertTime(time) {
  // Get the first 2 characters of 24H string and change them into a real number
  const H = parseInt(time.slice(0, 2), 10);
  let hour, meridiem;
  // if real number is greater than or equal to 12...
  if (H >= 12) {
    //...get the modulus of real number divided by 12 and change it to a string...
    hour = (H % 12).toString();
    //...and set to PM
    meridiem = " PM";
    // Otherwise...  
  } else {
    //...just change real number into a string...
    hour = H.toString();
    //...and set to AM
    meridiem = " AM";
  }
  // if formatted {hour} is 0...
  if (hour === "0") {
    //...change it to 12
    hour = "12";
  }
  // Get the 4th and 5th characters of 24H string
  const minute = time.slice(3, 5);
  // Pad {hour} with a 0 if it is only one character
  const hour12 = hour.padStart(2, 0);
  return hour12 + ':' + minute + meridiem;
}
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15ch
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for='checkIn'>Check In Time: </label><input type="time" id='checkIn' class="form-control" name="checkIn" required="">
  <hr>
  <label for='checkOut'>Check Out Time: </label><input type="time" id='checkOut' class="form-control" name="checkOut" required="">
</form>
```